# The magic number in gzip header is not correct

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, gzip

Task: there are 2 clients. They must compress byte array, send it, receive byte array, decompress it and do something with result.
I use TCP for sending and receiving.
The error arises in the decompress method.

Sending method:

```
private static void AsiooutOnAudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    audio = SamplesToBytes(monoSamples); 
    byte[] compressedBytes = CompressBytes(audio);

    if (_isConnected)
    {
        Task.Run(() => _receiver.BeginSend(compressedBytes, 0, compressedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, null));
    }
}
```

Receiving:

```
private static void Receive()
{
    _receiver.BeginReceive(incomingBytes, 0, incomingBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int receivedBytesCount = _receiver.EndReceive(ar);
    byte[] _audio = new byte[receivedBytesCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < receivedBytesCount; i++)
    {
        _audio[i] = incomingBytes[i];
    }
    var decompressBytes = DecompressBytes(_audio);
    _incomingBuffer.AddSamples(decompressBytes, 0, decompressBytes.Length);
    Receive();
}
```

Compression and decompression

```
public static byte[] CompressBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            gzip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}

static byte[] DecompressBytes(byte[] gzip)
{
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        int size = gzip.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size); //error place
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you receive the same bytes you are sending?

Comment: You forgot to design and implement some protocol for transporting the compressed data over TCP. You seem to be expecting it to work by magic. Perhaps you have the misconception that TCP is a *message* protocol. It's not. It's a byte stream protocol. If you need a message protocol (so that you can send compressed messages), you need to design and implement one.

Comment: The problem is in receiving method. I have byte array `incomingBytes` with 1024 length and receiver fills it fully. Sender may send more than one portions of data and receiver will putting that in the byte array, while the byte array is not full.